# Have black screen when running Flutter on real android device

Tags: flutter

When I run Flutter with either 'Start Debugging' or 'Run Without Debugging' would result in getting black screen on Vivo Y33s android device (*V2109 (mobile)    • 3422821381001Z0 • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)* on flutter devices terminal).
The vs code editor is stuck on 'Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...'.

The app is working when I run in terminal using flutter run command.
The app is also working perfectly in emulator or my older android model (Android 7). Is there any special permission to enable for running flutter on higher android version.

I try usb debugging mode enable with various connected option (like file transfer). I also select 'Select debug app' in developer option.

Comment: Is your compileSdkVersion in android/app/build.gradle set to 33?

Comment: Do you see any log in debug console?

Comment: I just found out that it has to do with vivo Funtouch OS, nothing is wrong with flutter, it is about Vivo phone problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @William Facing same issue on Vivo Y33s. How did you solved this?